# When is it valid to call inflateSetDictionary() when trying to decompress raw deflate data that was compressed with a dictionary?

Tags: c, zlib

### The Problem

When is it valid to call `inflateSetDictionary()` when trying to decompress raw deflate data that was compressed with a compression dictionary?

According to the [zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html), it is stated that `inflateSetDictionary()` can be called "at any time". However, it is unclear to me what "at any time" actually means. If we are allowed to call `inflateSetDictionary()` "at any time", then I interpret it as being valid to call `inflateSetDictionary()` after calling `inflate()`. However, doing so results in `inflate()` returning an "invalid distance too far back" error.

### My Code

I created a simple application to compress the string `"hello"` using raw deflate, with a compression dictionary that also consists of the byte sequence `"hello"`:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 16384
#define WINDOW_BITS -15 // Negative for raw.
#define MEM_LEVEL 8

const unsigned char dictionary[] = "hello";

unsigned char uncompressed[BUF_SIZE] = "hello";
unsigned char compressed[BUF_SIZE];

z_stream deflate_stream;

deflate_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
deflate_stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
deflate_stream.opaque = Z_NULL;

deflateInit2(&deflate_stream,
             Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
             Z_DEFLATED,
             WINDOW_BITS,
             MEM_LEVEL,
             Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);

deflateSetDictionary(&deflate_stream, dictionary, sizeof(dictionary));

deflate_stream.avail_in = (uInt)strlen(uncompressed) + 1;
deflate_stream.next_in = (Bytef *)uncompressed;

deflate_stream.avail_out = BUF_SIZE;
deflate_stream.next_out = (Bytef *)compressed;

deflate(&deflate_stream, Z_FINISH);

deflateEnd(&deflate_stream);
```

This produced 4 bytes of raw deflate data into the `compressed` buffer:

```
uLong compressed_size = deflate_stream.total_out;
printf("Compressed size is: %lu\n", compressed_size); // prints Compressed size is: 4
```

I then attempted to decompress this data back into the string "hello". The [zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html) states that I would need to use raw inflate to decompress raw deflate data:

```
unsigned char decompressed[BUF_SIZE];

z_stream inflate_stream;

inflate_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
inflate_stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
inflate_stream.opaque = Z_NULL;

inflateInit2(&inflate_stream, WINDOW_BITS);

inflate_stream.avail_in = (uInt)compressed_size;
inflate_stream.next_in = (Bytef *)compressed;

inflate_stream.avail_out = BUF_SIZE;
inflate_stream.next_out = (Bytef *)decompressed;

int r = inflate(&inflate_stream, Z_FINISH);
```

According to the [zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html), I would expect that `inflate()` should return `Z_NEED_DICT`, and I would then call `inflateSetDictionary()` with a subsequent call to `inflate()`:

```
// Must be called immediately after a call of inflate, if that call returned Z_NEED_DICT.
if (r == Z_NEED_DICT) {
    inflateSetDictionary(&inflate_stream, dictionary, sizeof(dictionary));
    r = inflate(&inflate_stream, Z_FINISH);
}

if (r != Z_STREAM_END) {
    printf("inflate: %s\n", inflate_stream.msg);
    return 1;
}

inflateEnd(&inflate_stream);

printf("Decompressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(decompressed));
printf("Decompressed string is: %s\n", decompressed);
```

However, what ends up happening is that `inflate()` will not return `Z_NEED_DICT`, and instead return `Z_DATA_ERROR`, with the value of `inflate_stream.msg` being set to `"invalid distance too far back"`.

Even if I were to adjust my code so that `inflateSetDictionary()` is called regardless of the return value of `inflate()`, the subsequent `inflate()` call will still fail with `Z_DATA_ERROR` due to `"invalid distance too far back"`.

### My Question

So far, my code works correctly if I were to use the default zlib encoding by setting `WINDOW_BITS` to `15`, as opposed to `-15` for the raw encoding.

My code also works correctly if I were to move the call for `inflateSetDictionary()` before the call to `inflate()`.

However, it's not clear to me why my existing code does not allow `inflate()` to return `Z_NEED_DICT`, so that I can make a subsequent call to `inflateSetDictionary()`.

Is there a mistake in my code somewhere that is preventing `inflate()` from returning `Z_NEED_DICT`? Or can `inflateSetDictionary()` only be called prior to `inflate()` for the raw encoding, contrary to what the [zlib manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html) states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inflate()` will only return `Z_NEED_DICT` for a zlib stream, where the need for a dictionary is indicated by a bit in the zlib header, followed by the Adler-32 of the dictionary that was used for compression to verify or select the dictionary. There is *no such indication* in a raw deflate stream. There is no way for `inflate()` to know from a raw deflate stream whether or not the data was compressed with a dictionary. It is up to *you* to know what is needed for decompression, since you made the raw deflate stream in the first place.

Since you did a `deflateSetDictionary()` before compressing anything, it is up to you to do an `inflateSetDictionary()` *at the same place*, before you decompress, after the `inflateInit()`. As you have found, you need to insert:

```
    inflateSetDictionary(&inflate_stream, dictionary, sizeof(dictionary));
```

right after the `inflateInit()`. Then decompression will be successful.

Yes, you can do `inflateSetDictionary()` at any point during a raw deflate decompression. However it will only *work* if you are doing it at the same point at which you did the corresponding `deflateSetDictionary()` when compressing.